# how to delete mac os x default input source

Tags: macos, input

how to delete mac os x ***default*** input source

os x:

> 10.12

default input source:

> English ABC

Screenshot:

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1890238/22072067/0e78f3ba-dddc-11e6-8b4e-10ecb744f197.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tutorial made by Topher Kessier in cnet. You may follow up on it here https://www.cnet.com/how-to/managing-input-methods-in-os-x/

This excerpt might help you:

```
To change your default input method in OS X and avoid having to make these
adjustments for each application and document you open, you first have to be
sure the setting to allow a different input source for each document is 
disabled. **To do this, go to the Input Sources system preferences and   
select the option to "Use the same one in all documents." With this setting 
in place, go to the input menu and select the desired method you would like    
to have as your primary input source.** After this is done, you can go back   
to allowing a different input source for each document, and any newly opened 
documents and applications will now use the desired primary input method, 
until you manually change it for that document.
```